# getMeasureWidth nullpointerexception in api before 19

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

I have a problem:

I´m inflating a relative layout and I need to measure the size of its contents. I use the following code :

```
....

    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);

    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.content);

    relativeLayout.measure(0,0);


    widthSoFar = widthSoFar + relative.getMeasuredWidth();


....
```

With the API´s before  of 19, the code not working, Error: NullPointerException in "relativelayout.measure(0,0)". But with the API 20 or 21 the  code working perfectly.

How I can do to measure the width with Api´s before 19?

Thanks

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(id, null, false);

    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.content);

    relativeLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    widthSoFar = widthSoFar + relative.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: I just try and not work. Android Studio returns the error: NullPointerException.